# How convert MQ Error to more descriptive text

Tags: ibm-mq, reasoning

How can I convert MQ API exception text to more descriptive text in my java app?
sample exception message >"MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2038'"
To > "An MQINQ call was issued to inquire object attributes, but the object had not been opened for inquire."
I have access to completion and reason code but not description.
Thanks

Comment: There is MQRC command that gives a little more info. Like 2038  0x000007f6  MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_INQUIRE.

Answer (score -1):

Go have a look at my open source projects: MQRC2 and MQRC2-GUI.  http://www.capitalware.biz/mqrc2_overview.html

MQRC2 is a command-line program and MQRC2-GUI is a Java/Swing program.